# Pandas web scraping(Beautiful soup) find in tag with class, another tag with a link. Then following the link inside href

Tags: pandas, beautifulsoup, tags

I tried fins 'td' tag with specific attribute, and then find 'a' tag inside of the 'td' tag

```
for row in bs4.find_all('<td class="series-column"'):
    for link in bs4.find_all('a'):
        if link.has_attr('href') and (link.has_attr('class') == 'formatted-title external-link result-url'):
            print(link.attrs['href'])
```

[image]

On the screenshot you see html for this page

Comment: Can you please share the URL your scraping from so that we can test it out?

Comment: https://knoema.com/search?query=world%20waste%20municipal%20waste%20collected%20which%20is%20recycled&scope=timeseries

Answer (score 2):

Your `bs4.find_all('<td class="series-column"')` is wrong. You have to supply tag name and attributes you want to find, for example `bs4.find_all('td', class_='series-column')`. Or use CSS selector:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


txt = '''
<td class="series-column">
    <a class="formatted-title external-link result-url" href="//knoema.com/...">link text</a>
</td>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

for link in soup.select('td.series-column a.formatted-title.external-link.result-url'):
    print(link['href'])
```

Prints:

```
//knoema.com/...
```